# How can i add multiple images link in this react-bootstrap card component?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

[Please see this code guys..how can i add multiple image link in this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCtEq.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean a carousel? a mosaic?...

Comment: Please provide your code as text and not as image. Also describe your problem a little bit more. Your question is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in subcomponent Card.Img, then only one image is possible. But you don't have to use it. Feel free to use only Card, or Card with Card.Body - in the end it's only styling!

As you didn't say how those multiple images should be arranged, I added four images inline above the card text:

```
<Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Card.Body>
          <Stack
            direction="horizontal"
            className="justify-content-between mb-3"
          >
            <img src="holder.js/50x50" alt="img-1" />
            <img src="holder.js/50x50" alt="img-1" />
            <img src="holder.js/50x50" alt="img-1" />
            <img src="holder.js/50x50" alt="img-1" />
          </Stack>
          <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-easley-xy5xi5